# Detect cracks on image_ Using the scikit-image label to modify image

Tags: python, object, detection, scikit-image

Here is my context : I have an image of a concrete wall, on which I want to detect cracks. Based on this guys idea (https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cee_facpub/1234/) and other state of the art approaches, I have applied to my grayscale image Otsu thresholding and a morphological operation (closing), so the pixels of the image are from 0 (background) to 1.

Now, what I want to do : I would like to remove from the image the connected pixels that are vertical or horizontal (ie the pipe on the wall for example).
To do so, I use the following code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops, regionprops_table
from skimage import filters
from math import *

img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Caroline/Documents/myimage.tif', -1) 

label_img = label(img) #Label the different regions of the image
regions = regionprops_table(label_img, properties=('label', 'orientation')) #Compute the properties "orientation" of each regions

orientinter = list(regions.values())
orientradian = orientinter[1] #kind of a conversion to only get the orientation with an array and not a dictionary
orientationdeg = orientradian * 180/pi #conversion in degrees from radians

v1=np.where(abs(orientationdeg)<1) #getting the index of the objects that are horizontals
v2=np.where(abs(orientationdeg)>89) #getting the index of the objects that are verticals

#eventually merging v1 and v2 to have a triple of "every index of the regions I want to get rid of"
```

My question is : from now, how can I keep going ? I mean, I have the index/label (not sure of the vocabulary) of the regions I want to merge with the background (assign the value 0 for those pixels on the picture). But I am lost on how to do the "link" between the region index/label and the image, and how to assign those region to 0 in the image.
In pseudo-code, I think it will be something like this :

```
for the regions in merge(v1 and v2)
   set their pixel values to 0 in LabelImg
```

Thank you for your help and comments !

Answer (score 1):

(New to the website so I don't know if it is commun procedure to answer to your own  question when you find the answer)

Here is the code I used to get to job done ! It may need to be update for efficiency, as well as the preprocessing steps.  Hope it helps someone else on day.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops, regionprops_table
from skimage import filters
from math import *

img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Caroline/Documents/myimg.tif', -1) 

label_img = label(img) #Label the image
regions = regionprops_table(label_img, properties=('label', 'orientation')) #Compute properties 'label' et 'orientation' of each regions

orientinter = list(regions.values())
orientradian = orientinter[1] #conversion in array
orientationdeg = orientradian * 180/pi #conversion en degré

L = [(abs(orientationdeg) < 89) & (abs(orientationdeg) >1)] #return list with true ou false
#True beeing the region that are NOT horizontal/vertical
V = newList[0] #conversion of the list in array
r = V*1 #there will be zeros for the regions horizontal/vertical, and the orientation otherwise

Vprime= np.argwhere(r)+1 #get the non zeros index of. +1 because index starts at 0, and we want labels, they start at 1
#now Vprime is all the labels of non vertical/horizontal regions

a=np.in1d(label_img, Vprime)*1 #the ismember matlab fonction, for this application
img_final=np.reshape(a,label_img.shape)

#Export final image
```

Comment: Answering your own questions if you figure them out before getting a reply is very much encouraged.